# Getting XML value in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a column in a SQL Server table which is of datatype `XML`. I am trying to query an element from that XML column, but I'm failing.

The XML and the query is below. Appreciate if someone can help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfDataValue xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <DataValue>
      <FieldValue>Activity</FieldValue>
      <FirstOutput xsi:type="xsd:string">Play</FirstOutput>
      <SecondOutput xsi:type="xsd:string">Sleep</SecondOutput>
   </DataValue>
   <DataValue>
      <FieldValue>Count</FieldValue>
      <FirstOutput xsi:type="xsd:string">21</FirstOutput>
      <SecondOutput xsi:type="xsd:string">25</SecondOutput>
   </DataValue>
   <DataValue>
      <FieldValue>Area</FieldValue>
      <FirstOutput xsi:type="xsd:string">City</FirstOutput>
      <SecondOutput xsi:type="xsd:string">Country</SecondOutput>
   </DataValue>
</ArrayOfDataValue>
```

Query:

```
Select 
    [xmlfield].value('(/DataValue//FirstOutput/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FieldName
```

The output I am looking for is to get the Values of FieldValue, FirstOutput and SecondOutput

Example:

```
FirstOutput
Play
```

It is a SQL Server database

Comment: What database provider? Please, provide information about expected output too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply maciej, i have edited and added what u have asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    FieldValue = XC.value('(FieldValue)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    FirstOutput = XC.value('(FirstOutput)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    SecondOutput = XC.value('(SecondOutput)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
CROSS APPLY
    XmlColumn.nodes('/ArrayOfDataValue/DataValue') AS XT(XC)
```

Replace `dbo.YourTableNameHere` with your actual table name, and `XmlColumn` with the name of your `XML` column.

You should get an output something like:

[image]

Comment: It is returning null for me

Comment: No, it is perfect as given. It just returns a null value. I have just copy-pasted your code and changed the table name and column name.

Comment: @Santu: If your XML looks exactly as you showed it, and you copy-pasted my exact code - then you will **NOT** get `NULL` ..... as shown in my response. Something is off - your XML is different, or the code you're running isn't what I posted. Double- and triple-check both the XML and your code - there must be a difference somewhere

Comment: XML is also very susceptible to lower-/UPPER-case - are the names for the XML elements ***exactly*** as they appear in the XML ?? Or are they possible **attributes** instead of elements? Something **must be** different ...

Comment: Yes Got it. Perfect. Thank you so much. Sorry i was missing that XC